# Can i debug with Cling? Any API?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, cling

Does [cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) (as embeddable interpreter) support code debugging? Any API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't provide debugging features.